# How to Update Current Datetime using UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to update my current Datetime in the date_commit Field

```
 class UpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ['date_commit']
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the problem you're facing while doing this?

Comment: Actually, in my case, there are two DateTime fields such as start and stop, so when I put datetime.datetime.now() in the models.py, they updated both fields. So I want to update the single field (stop) through the update view. So, I can easily measure the distance between start and stop. So please tell me how to do this code or any source useful to me.